# how to add class to the wordpress primary dropdown menu

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to add class name to the primary sub-menu in wordpress. Please any one help me to do this. thanks in advance.

for example menu structure like this

```
<ul id="main-menu">
<li><a href=""> home</a></li>
<li><a href="">About us</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="">submenu1</a></li>
<li><a href="">submenu2</a></li>
<li><a href="">submenu3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

i want to add another class in the sub-menu `ul`

Comment: Never used wordpress so I don't know but you could do this by using jQuery. Something like `$(".sub-menu").addClass("yourClass");`

Comment: It depends on what theme you are using and how this theme generates the menu. Can you provide the code?

Comment: But I want to add the class to the wordpress main submenu for animate the view of submenu.

Comment: i am using this following theme to my site https://themeisle.com/demo/?theme=Zerif%20Lite

Comment: or tell me how to add animation for the sub menu appearance on hover in wordpress website?

Comment: By default WP adds `.menu-item-has-children` to any menu item that contains other items (i.e. a submenu). Can you use that class? Or does it *have* to be the `.sub-menu` class.

Comment: is it solved???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work , just add this code to your **functions.php**

```
function your_submenu_class($menu) {

$menu = preg_replace('/ class="sub-menu"/','/ class="sub-menu yourclass" /',$menu);  

return $menu;  

}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu','your_submenu_class');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `'menu_class'` argument of `wp_nav_menu()` function in `.php` template:

```
  <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
      'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
      'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
      'menu_class'      => 'menu  primary-menu-top'
    ) );
  ?>
```

Comment: How do you add class to parent dropdown